# How do I express O(n) * O(n log n)

Tags: big-o

I'm writing a report where I need to present some results with Big O notation. Since I have not used Big O notations before, I'm a bit unsure of how to write.

I understand that if you have O(n) * O(n) then the result becomes O(n^2). For example, a loop in a loop.

And O(n) * O(log n) equals O(n log n).For example, if you need to loop over a funktion that search in a balanced binary tree.

But if I have to loop a function with time complexity O(n log n).

How do I write O(n) * O(n log n) correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's just normal multiplication of whatever is inside the `O`.

```
n * n*log(n) = n^2*log(n)
```

So it's:

```
O(n^2 log n)
```